# Making a query to get elements active on a time between 2 specific dates

Tags: laravel

Cant seem to get the logic right. I have a function that takes 2 dates (**$date1** and **$date2**). I have database records of events that also have 2 dates (**starting_at** and **ending_at**).

**I want to get all events that completely or partially overlap with time between $date1 and $date2**. I have browsed other similar topics and came up with this... but i have a feeling it is not correct.

```
$events = Event::with(['user']);

    $events->where(function($query) use ($date1,$date2) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($date2) {
            $query->where('starting_at', '<=', $date2);
        });
        $query->where(function($query) use ($date1) {
            $query->where('ending_at', '>=', $date1);
        });
    });
```

Comment: is your `date1` your `from` and `date2` your `to`? if yes, then you could do 
where('starting_at','>=','$date1') and where('ending_at','<=','$date2')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dates are in the same table, use:

```
$events = Event::with('user')
               ->where('starting_at', '<=', $date2)
               ->where('ending_at', '>=', $date1)
               ->get();
```

Make sure you've added `starting_at` and `ending_at` to the [`dates` array](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators):

```
protected $dates = ['starting_at', 'ending_at'];
```

Comment: I wonder though... Will this work if, for example, $date1 and $date2 are beginning and end of current week but the event started at the beginning of current month and ends at the end of current month. I am using Laravel 5.3.

Comment: There could be any length for events and the $date1 and $date2 can be any time length (from couple of hours to years)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a simple way of doing this.

```
$events = Event::with(['user'])->whereBetween('field_name', array($date1, $date2))->get();
```

Check the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

**UPDATE**

If `date1` and `date2` are from entirely different columns on the database, then refer @Alexey Mezenin answer which is more appropriate.

Comment: I thought it will work too, but since OP has dates in separate columns, `whereBetween()` will not work.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, you are correct, the OP refers to separate column, updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try @AlexeyMezenin answer

Answer (score 1):

With Laravel 5.3 (maybe 5.2, but 5.3 for sure) you can do:

```
$events = $events->whereBetween($date1, $date2)->get();
```

Lower version could be:

```
$events = $events->where('starting_at', '<=', $date2)
                 ->where('ending_at', '>=', $date1)
                 ->get();
```

Comment: I wonder though... Will this work if, for example, $date1 and $date2 are beginning and end of current week but the event started at the beginning of current month and ends at the end of current month. I am using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Yeah sure! You should use the "lower version" answer though, which is the same as @Alexey Mezenin